# what is the impact tp disable elasticsearch in sonarqube

Tags: elasticsearch, sonarqube

I am using sonarqube 5.6.3, and found elasticsearch always crash after analysis 5k ~ 50k projects, I intend to disable elasticsearch, is it doable and what is the impact?

Answer (score 1):

Nope, SonarQube won't work without Elasticsearch.

I highly suggest to post your crash with your environment and the log files to the forum at https://groups.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!forum/sonarqube